# push object to an already existed javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, push, addition

I use nodejs and mongodb.

I get dictionary res from the following mongodb query :

```
Profile.find(search,['_id', 'username'],function(err, res)
```

printing res look like :

```
[
    {
        "username": "dan",
        "_id": "508179a3753246cd0100000e"
    },
    {
        "username": "mike",
        "_id": "508317353d1b33aa0e000010"
    }
]
}
```

I would like to push to each of the res[x] another key value pair :

```
[
    {
        "username": "dan",
        "_id": "508179a3753246cd0100000e",
        "more info": {
            "weight": "80",
            "height": "175"
        }
    },
    {
        "username": "mike",
        "_id": "508317353d1b33aa0e000010"
    },
    "more info": {
        "weight": "80",
        "height": "175"
    }
]
}
```

I've tried :

`var x=0`
`dic = []`
`while (x<res.length){`
    `dic[x] = {}`
    `dic[x]=res[x]`
        `dic[x]["more info"] = {"wight" : weight, "height" : hight}`
        `x=x+1`
`}`
but it is ignored and I get

```
[
    {
        "username": "dan",
        "_id": "508179a3753246cd0100000e"
    },
    {
        "username": "mike",
        "_id": "508317353d1b33aa0e000010"
    }
]
}
```

appreciate your help.

Comment: [Format your code.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Can't spell weight and height? :) Where is x being defined? Where is it being incremented?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead.

```
for (var x = 0, len = res.length; x < len; ++x) { ... }
```

You need to initialize the variable `x` first (`var x = 0`) and then increment it after each execution of the loop (`++x` or `x += 1`).

**Update:**

Oh, ok. Why are you event creating the new array (`dic`) by the way? Object in JavaScript are passed by reference so if you just modify the individual results (res[0], res[1]), you get the same.

`dic[x] = {}; dic[x] = res[x]` does not make sense as you create a new object (`{}`) and then immediately overwrite it with the object `res[x]` points to.

Try this:

```
 res.forEach(function (item) {
   item['more info'] = { weight: weight, height: height };
 });

 console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that's not the problem, I just forgot to write it in the question

Comment: thanks again. still 'more info' is being ignored! even tried : item.save()

Comment: Wait, are you checking the result immediately or are you requesting the items from the database again expecting them to be updated? If you use `item.save()`, you need to wait for the change to be stored in the database and retrieve the items again after that. Use a callback function to do that. There is surely a readme for your mongodb driver.

Comment: I'm checking the result immediately. the only solution I found is creating a new dictionary and copy each key and value one at a time and then add the key and value i want. It seems very non efficient to go through the result and copy each key and value for the purpose of adding one more key value pair to the result but it seems like the only way